# Is it normal that the ad-hoc url doesn't work in the simulator?

Tags: ios, safari, xcode, enterprise

I'd like to test my app's ad-hoc deployment link, but navigating to the URL in the simulator's browser only returns  'Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid'. The URL I use looks like `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=[URL TO MYAPP.PLIST]` Where going to the apended URL downloads the plist file.

I used XCode 5.1 to archive the build and export it for enterprise distribution with the correct certificates and such. Is the error still somewhere in my build or is this type of install capability turned off for the simulators?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the itms:// type links don't work in the simulator.